# Configuring Munin's Tomcat plugin for Tomcat 8

Tags: tomcat, munin, tomcat8

Hi i've followed several guides about configuring tomcat plugin on a munin node but all of them was for tomcat 6 although i did neccessary corrections in tomcat-users.xml and whatnot, i couldn't get any data from the plugin.

Is there anyone who did this for Tomcat 8?

Edit : The steps i've followed :

Create symlinks :

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/munin/plugins/tomcat_access /etc/munin/plugins/tomcat_access
 sudo ln -s /usr/share/munin/plugins/tomcat_jvm /etc/munin/plugins/tomcat_jvm
 sudo ln -s /usr/share/munin/plugins/tomcat_threads /etc/munin/plugins/tomcat_threads
 sudo ln -s /usr/share/munin/plugins/tomcat_volume /etc/munin/plugins/tomcat_volume
```

Edit tomcat-users.xml :

`<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
 <user username="munin" password="secret" roles="manager-gui"/>`

Create manager.xml :

```
<Context privileged="true" antiResourceLocking="false"
         docBase="${catalina.home}/webapps/manager">
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
         allow="127\.0\.0\.1" />
</Context>
```

Edit munin-node conf in plugin-conf.d :

```
[tomcat_*]
env.ports 8080
env.user munin
env.password secret
```

Run plugins :

```
munin-run tomcat_access
```

Restart munin node :

```
sudo service munin-node restart
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: Please don't edit the answer into your question. [sf] is a question and answer site and answers should be separate from questions. You can [answer your own question](http://serverfault.com/help/self-answer) instead.

Comment: Alright will do that instead, sorry. 

Answered and edit approved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found myself a solution :

What I did was create a manager.xml in `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/Catalina/localhost` and add these inside :

```
<Context privileged="true" antiResourceLocking="false"
         docBase="${catalina.home}/webapps/manager">
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve" allow="^.*$" />
</Context>
```

Of course, you need to change the "allow" section however you want, if you need to access from a remote host you should write the ip there.

After this in `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/context.xml` I commented out this line :

`<!-- <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SSLAuthenticator" securePagesWithPragma="false" />-->`

I absolutely don't know what this will cause but it let me login into the manager page.

Finally added these to the munin-node configuration :

```
env.host 127.0.0.1
env.request /manager/status?XML=true
env.ports 8080
env.connector "http-nio-8080"
```

You can find the correct connector in the manager web page. Hope this helps someone else too.